# New badge, e.g. a Python gold badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I saw somebody with a `Python gold badge` but can't dig up where now... This badge isn't listed on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/badges).  Where is the reference?

Comment: Check this page http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags - it means that they've earned 1000 up-votes on questions tagged `python`. There's been 6 badges awarded as of now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the ["tags" tab of the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags).

Look in the upper right part of the page, just below "Ask Question"; there you'll see the two tabs, "general" and "tags". Now imagine a circle around "tags".

(When they added the tabs, it took me at least a month to notice them.)